# Laravel group 2 Collection by key

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I'm working on a Laravel Project, and got a problem,
I get from the database 2 things (expenses and payments), which returns a collection object.
I need to group them by key, here are the arrays :

```
    [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [date_payment] => 2018-01-01
                [total_payment] => 19761.62
            )

    )

)

Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [date_payment] => 2018-01-29
                [total_charges] => 5184.4399862289
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [date_payment] => 2017-09-04
                [total_charges] => 0
            )

    )

 )
```

I need it to be like that :

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [date_payment] => 2018-01-29
                [total_charges] => 5184.4399862289
                [total_payment] => 19761.62
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [date_payment] => 2017-09-04
                [total_charges] => 0
            )

    )

   )
```

I've tried everything, I check on Google, check the Laravel doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-union And I saw nothing to do it, I tried with the method union/merge, but don't do what I want

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a collection named `$payments`:

```
$payment = new StdClass;
$payment->date_payment = '2018-01-01';
$payment->total_payment = 19761.62;

$payments = collect([
    $payment
]);
```

And another collection named `$expenses`:

```
$expense1 = new StdClass();
$expense1->date_payment = '2018-01-29';
$expense1->total_charges = 5184.4399862289;

$expense2 = new StdClass();
$expense2->date_payment = '2017-09-04';
$expense2->total_charges = 0;

$expenses = collect([
    $expense1, $expense2
]);
```

To retrieve the elements that has the same keys in both collection, you can do it with `intersectByKeys`:

```
$payments->intersectByKeys($expenses);
```

This will retrieve all the payments that has a common key with the expenses collection.

Now, to update the values of the collection, you can use the `transform` function:

```
$payments->transform(function ($payment, $index) use ($expenses) {
    $expense = $expenses->get($index);
    $payment->date_payment = $expense->date_payment;
    $payment->total_charges = $expense->total_charges;

    return $payment;
});
```

Now if you combine both of them together:

```
$payments->intersectByKeys($expenses)->transform(function ($payment, $index) use ($expenses) {
    $expense = $expenses->get($index);
    $payment->date_payment = $expense->date_payment;
    $payment->total_charges = $expense->total_charges;

    return $payment;
});
```

### Output

```
Collection {#277 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#272 ▼
      +"date_payment": "2018-01-29"
      +"total_payment": 19761.62
      +"total_charges": 5184.4399862289
    }
  ]
}
```

For more information:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-intersectbykeys

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But for some reasons, Laravel say me this method doesn't exist, I'm in 5.5.* in composer, but anyway, I'll try to find a "hack" to do it

Comment: @ThéoBenoit As of `5.5`, the method changed to `intersectByKeys`. Look at my update. I thought you were on `5.4` because you linked the docs of `5.4`...

Comment: Thanks for your interest, It should have worked, I made a function to do that myself sadly, but thanks for your help sir